# FindRoot::nlnum and InterpolatingFunction::dprec problem

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation, precision-and-accuracy

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f0 = 10^13;
sol1 = DeleteCases[Quiet[NDSolve[Rationalize[{y1'[x] + 4 y1[x]/x == 0,
  y1[f0/f0] == 33*f0^4}], {y1}, {x, f0/10^13, f0/10^-15}, 
Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, AccuracyGoal -> 50, 
PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxSteps -> 100000]], ComplexInfinity]
A[z_] := 10^-19 Sqrt[Evaluate[(y1[f0/z]) /. sol1]];
cT = 10^Range[-10, 15, 0.1];
Nt = Length[cT];
ZZ = Table[0, {i, 1, Nt}];
Do[ZZ[[i]] = z /. FindRoot[cT[[i]]*10^18 == 1/(2 A[z]), {z, 10^-7}], {i, 1, Nt}]
```

The last line of the code producing `FindRoot::nlnum` and `InterpolatingFunction::dprec` problem, Can it be solved with other ways like `NSolve`

Comment: You could try constraining `FindRoot` to the domain of `sol1`: e.g. `{z, 10^-7, 10^-15, 10^13}`.  Side note: I don't know what you think `DeleteCases[]` is doing, but I think it's not doing it. (It does nothing.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 after taking the domain of `sol1` these two errors are gone. However, there is still a warning `FindRoot::lstol`. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Yes, I get `FindRoot::lstol`, too. But I got that message with your original code and you didn't ask about it.  So I figured you understood it and knew what you wanted to do.